# Error message: "expected an indented block"

Tags: python

So i am trying to code a game and i am trying to connect the different areas of the level.This part of the code is supposed to allow the user to chose were to go in the level but the terminal keeps giving me this error command: `"expected an indented block"`.

I have tried to replace all the tabs with four spaces and vice-versa but the error wont go away.

**By the way I do know that after defining a function each line afterwards would be indented four spaces or a tab but this is my first question and I couldn't figure out how to do that here.**

---

```
def entry_hall():   
    first = raw_input("Go upstairs\nGo forwards\nGo left\nLeave\n:")
    if first == "Go upstairs" or "upstairs":
        print "Walking up the stairs" 
        import Upstairs_hallway.py
    elif first == "Go forwards" or "forwards":
        pass
    elif first == "Go left" or "left":
        pass
    elif first == "Leave":
        print """
You're a cop. You are not a baby. Do something else
""" 
        #restart the script

entry_hall()
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace (i.e. line numbers)

Comment: Highlight code and press Ctl-k to format as a code block.  Please edit your code to make it look like it _really_ looks, since that is what is important here. -- I just noticed that you already know about the indentation...

Comment: You almost certainly don't really want a conditional import like that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your indentation is constant:

```
def entry_hall():   
    first = raw_input("Go upstairs\nGo forwards\nGo left\nLeave\n:")

    if first in ["Go upstairs", "upstairs"]:
        print "Walking up the stairs" 
        import Upstairs_hallway
    elif first == "Go forwards" or "forwards":
        pass
    elif first == "Go left" or "left":
        pass
    elif first == "Leave":
        print "You're a cop. You are not a baby. Do something else" 
        #restart the script

entry_hall()
```

Also, `if  first == "Go upstairs" or "upstairs"` won't work very well. That statement will be evaluated as this:

```
if (first == "Go upstairs") or "upstairs"
```

The first condition, `first == "Go upstairs"`, may evaluate to either `True` or `False`, but the second condition, `"upstairs"`, will always evaluate to `True`. Because you're using an `or` statement as well, your first condition will *always* evaluate to `True`.

Using a list will fix this problem:

```
if first in ["Go upstairs", "upstairs"]:
```

Also, in Python, `import` statements don't expect there to be a `.py` extension. Just supply the file name:

```
import Upstairs_hallway
```

Comment: im pretty new to programing so I was just wondering what 'if first == "Go upstairs" or "upstairs"' would have done

Comment: @user1626188: See my edit. I wrote a brief explanation of what would happen.

Comment: @ blender thanks i did see that but when I replaced my old stuff with this the same error message popped up

Comment: Post the full traceback and all of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just add four more characters after each line of code after the `def`:

```
def entry_hall():   
    first = raw_input("Go upstairs\nGo forwards\nGo left\nLeave\n:")
```

Answer (score 0):

My original answer is not needed, since you say the bad alignment of the `def` statement is due to not knowing how to paste it properly in Markdown.

You do have another problem, though: your `if` statements are wrong.  Swap `if s == 'first' or 'second':` for `if s in ['first', 'second']:`—the former will always be true, because `'second'` evaluates to true.